# pause on hover for simple jquery carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, carousel

I've set up an example of a super simple functioning carousel here:

http://codepen.io/anon/full/myvAz

The problem is, I cannot get the carousel to stop rotating on hover.

I can't even get an alert to fire on hovering over the containing div, even though it has a set width and height.
I can however get am alert to fire if i paste the hover section into console.

It just doesn't seem to fire when combined with the other code.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Heres the code:

```
<script>
// Main image carousel
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#headerMrS > div:gt(0)").hide();

var carouDiv = function(){
    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#headerMrS > div:first')
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#headerMrS');
    },  2000);
};

$(carouDiv());//Initialise the carousel function

$("#headerMrS").hover(function(){//Stop the carousel on hover
 $(this).stop;
  },function(){
  $(this).resume;
});


//Direction Arrow links
$(".button-sales").click(function(){
    $(".header").fadeOut(800);
    $(".sales").animate({opacity:"show"},800);
});
$(".button-modern").click(function(){
    $(".header").fadeOut(800);
    $(".modern").animate({opacity:"show"},800);
});
$(".button-antique").click(function(){
    $(".header").fadeOut(800);
    $(".antique").animate({opacity:"show"},800);
});
});
```

```
<style>

#headerMrS {position:relative; height:150px; width:350px}
.header {position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
</style>

<div id="headerMrS">
<div class="header sales active">
    <div class="header-content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/4787ed/ffffff" alt="" />
        <div class="button-next button-antique">next</div>
        <div class="button-prev button-modern">prev</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header antique">
    <div class="header-content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/fc8a41/ffffff" alt="" />

        <div class="button-next button-modern">next</div>
        <div class="button-prev button-sales">prev</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="header modern">
    <div class="header-content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/e7376b/ffffff" alt="" />

        <div class="button-next button-sales">next</div>
        <div class="button-prev button-antique">prev</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which code? I can see only a link here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `clearInterval()` ?

Instead of simply calling `setInterval()`, assign the `setInterval()` function to a variable, below I use `carouselInt`. This is necessary for calling `clearInterval()`.
To stop the interval you would then call `clearInterval(carouselInt)`

From what I've just read, `stop()` will stop the current animation, but you have a new animation every 2 seconds. It has no apparent effect on setInterval, which is causing the animation to fire.

You could try the following.

```
var carouselInt = '';

var carouDiv = function(){
    carouselInt = setInterval(function() { 
      $('#headerMrS > div:first')
        .fadeOut(500)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(500)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#headerMrS');
    },  2000);
};

$(carouDiv());//Initialise the carousel function

$("#headerMrS").hover(function(){//Stop the carousel on hover
 clearInterval(carouselInt);
  },function(){
  carouDiv();
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks that seems to work a treat! I tried using setInterval but had no luck.. Something about the way you have passed clearInterval an anonymous variable has solved this right?

Comment: You assign the setInterval function to a variable, and pass that variable to the clearInterval function when you need it. I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: Can you please assist with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39598240/how-to-modify-script-to-make-carousel-continuous-and-pause-on-hover

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an unclosed script tag around line 63 of your HTML - could that be the issue?

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see it.. It all looks closed ok

Comment: AGreed, `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
(function() {

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
<script>
// Main image carousel` 2 open script-tags at `<script> (function() { <script src=`